# How to interpret this lua expression with multiple logical operations in one line?

Tags: lua

This expression seems very strange to me.

```
nEpochs = nEpochs == 0 and 164 or nEpochs?
```

I've tried to understand the logical operator with integers, such as

```
100 and 164
-- output is 164
0 and 1
-- output is 1
1 and -1
-- output is -1
```

I don't quite understand what does all these mean. Can anybody give me a hand?